# Google Analytics - Shows 'New Users' but 'Users' don't appear

Tags: google-analytics

In the **Acquisition** tab:
**New Users** is appearing as expected.
But **Users** is appearing as **0**.

All is fine in the **Audience** tab.

Any ideas why this might be happening?

Screenshot:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/WEdBj.jpg

Comment: I've never seen this before, but have you got **Enable Users Metric in Reporting** turned on under the Property settings > User Analysis?

Comment: Yeah it's pretty odd! Enable Users Metric in Reporting is turned on... It's particularly odd that it's only occurring in the Acquisition tab. Maybe I'll hit up the Google forums, I'll report back if I find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Issue resolved itself after 48 hours.. Possible caching issue?